# Why does Facebook not want to display my post thumbnails?

Tags: post-thumbnails, facebook

Recently when I try to share my content on Facebook, everything appears normal except I cannot get it to display a picture. I'm using WordPress SEO to handle all of the SEO and Social metadata, but it doesn't really cover images that well.

When I use the Facebook Debugger, my webpages do not contain errors yet it still refuses to display images. I think the problem is happening because it is selecting the photo media using this format of link: http://media.detailsofmylife.net/uploads/2012/03/Alesso-Essential-Mix-200x125.jpg , but I am not sure why:

- Why Facebook chooses that as the default image even though I have the full size version selected as the Featured Image.
- Why Facebook has a problem with that format style of link image?

Any ideas or suggestions would be much appreciated as it's doing my head in!

Comment: Close-voted as **off-topic**. This is a **Facebook OpenGraph protocol** question, *not* a **WordPress** question. (P.S. did you try **[searching the site for "Facebook + opengraph"](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=facebook+opengraph)** before posting your question?

Comment: Well I do consider it a Wordpress question as I also want to know why those particular thumbnails are being generated and chosen.

Comment: But how does that make this question related to *WordPress*? The FB OpenGraph API is simply looking at images within the rendered content. *How* that content gets rendered is mostly irrelevant at that point - so it could be static HTML, or content generated by WordPress or any other CMS...

Comment: Because I think is has a problem with the link style that is generated by the Wordpress thumbnails, therefore it is wholly to do with Wordpress. The dimensions of the thumbnail are being included in the image link, and although Facebook recognises to og:image reference, it refuses to display the image. Therefore I was wondering whether changing the link style would solve my issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you define a meta tag with the og:image property, facebook will pick this up as the image associated with that url.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/

Comment: Hi Nick, I had already done this prior to posting but facebook still refuses to display the image, even when I lint the url using the developer tools.

Comment: i get errors for your site with both facebook's linter and scraper [https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.detailsofmylife.net%2Fmusic-videos%2Fjessie-ware-devotion%2F](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.detailsofmylife.net%2Fmusic-videos%2Fjessie-ware-devotion%2F)

Comment: Hi Nick, if it's a parsing error then I've been getting that too today for some reason, but I've got no idea why. If I try it until it properly resolves though it doesn't show any errors with the Open Graph Information. For example [I just posted](http://i.imgur.com/3j6nQ.jpg) that Jesse Ware link on Facebook and it displays properly, although before it didn't.

Comment: Your site has too many errors that need corrected before you can diagnose this problem.  Your about page is returning a 503 status with facebook [https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.detailsofmylife.net%2Fabout](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.detailsofmylife.net%2Fabout).  Also you might have permissions problems and I see mod_pagespped is enabled.  This might have someting to do with it.

Comment: I also see a random ?  I think you might have an improperly closed php tag.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it seems that the crawler is just having a bug. I have my own canonical answer in this question, hope that helps you: [FB OpenGraph og:image not pulling images (possibly https?)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57606813/3416774)

Answer (score -1):

When you have maximum users from Facebook and other social media networks instead of organic traffic then Facebook blocks your URL due to multiple shares.
and in some cases facebook block you from showing thumbnails. you can request to facebook for this.

or if your thumbnails are not showing and you are using mobile facebook then Also try it on laptop. in some cases thumbnain on laptop shown if you provide some spaces or some text after the link

Comment: That doesn't sound right to me. How would Facebook know how much traffic you get from other sources? Why would they care? I'm sure they'd be happy to be your sole advertisement platform..

Comment: my website was facing the same issue, and i solve this isssue, just by sending feedback request to facebook,